# VBA macro copy/paste names to specific sheets if conditions are met. loop to next row, repeat

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I have a VBA question on how to create a macro that will copy/paste names to specific worksheets if conditions are met. A few examples below...

- B12 is **Yes**. **Include** is 1. **Exclude** is 0. Therefore, copy/paste **NameG1** to cell A1 of **Name_Inc_1**. Save workbook to desktop as **Report1** (column D). Clear A1 from all tabs (besides Setup tab) then move to next row.
- B13 is **Yes**. **Include** is 2; **Exclude** is 1. Therefore, copy/paste **NameG2** to cell A1 of **Name_Inc_1**. Also, copy/paste **NameH1** to cell A1 of **Name_Inc_2** (because include tab is 2). Copy/paste **NameM1** to cell A1 of **Name_Exc_1**. Save workbook to desktop as **Report2** (column D). Clear A1 from all tabs (besides Setup tab) then move to next row.
- B14 is **No**. Move to next row. No need to save workbook or clear tab (already cleared).

The code I attempted is messy and not helpful (I have just started learning VBA). Googling things isn't helping me too much right now. I know I would use code such as IF, ELSE, THEN, LOOP but I am just getting confused.

[image: image of excel using snipping tool]

Your help is very much appreciated!.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Even if you think your code is not helpful, please post it. That way, we can give specific help and not just write code for you

Comment: A different approach with the same result is to open a workbook with all the sheets and delete the unwanted sheets. Use a `For` through the rows, around an `If` about Yes or No, around a `For` through the columns, around an `If` about whether there is a name or empty cell. For each cell in B12:B101... If cell="Yes", then open a workbook with all the sheets... For i=1 to 8... If cell.Offset(0, 4+i).Text<>"", then workbook.Sheets(i).Range("A1") = cell.Offset(0, 4+i).Text, else delete workbook.Sheets(i).Range("A1")... Next i... Save the workbook with the name cell.Offset(0, 2).Text... Next cell.